# Prevent Display Of Html Tags From User Input Sinatra?

Tags: ruby, heroku, sinatra

I have an app where users can input whatever they want, and it will show up on a separate page. I would like to have it display exactly what the user inputs and not process the tags as html. For example if a user inputs `let me use a <hr>` it will not actually create a horizontal line, it will output `let me use a <hr>`. This would have to do this universally for all html tags in user input.

Comment: What have you tried? What problems did you have?  I would have thought that putting a `<pre>` tag around the field in the view would do it, but I could be missing the point entirely -- without code from you or trying it myself, it's hard to know what the problems here actually are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I do it in my app, add the following to app.rb:

```
helpers do
  include Rack::Utils
  alias_method :h, :escape_html
end
```

Then in your view you can do:

```
<%= h user_input %>
```

Comment: I will try that. I read about using the h function, but I always got an error about not declaring it.

Answer (score 0):

I actually ended up solving my own problem. I wrote this function:

```
def func(var)
     var = var.gsub(/[<]/,"&lt")
     var = var.gsub(/[>]/,"&gt")
end
```

And called it on any string that I needed to insert into my HTML.

Comment: The will work, but please DO NOT use this, using regex like this will not protect you from XSS attacks.